# por que me da este error al compliar? error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java

Me ayudan tengo este error donde la clase MENU esta dentro del mismo paquete

> PIMSystem.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
> Menu myMenu = new Menu();
> ^
> symbol:   class Menu
> location: class PIMSystem
> PIMSystem.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
> Menu myMenu = new Menu();
> ^
> symbol:   class Menu
> location: class PIMSystem
> 2 errors

```
package ec.edu.espe.pim.view;

public class PIMSystem {
        public static void main (String[] args){
            
            Menu myMenu = new Menu();
            myMenu.mainMenu();           
        }
}
```

Comment: Tienes la clase Menu?

Comment: No tienes un constructor en la otra clase?

Comment: No es que no te creamos pero.. cómo está definida la clase menú? si está en el mismo paquete, tiene problemas de definición

Answer (score 4):

El error

> cannot find symbol

Ocurre cuando intentas hacer referencia a una variable o Clase no declarada en tu código, en este caso se refiere a que no puede encontrar la clase, por dos causas:

- La clase no existe y no se puede hacer referencia a ella.
- La clase existe pero no estas agregando el `import` necesario para acceder a ella.